# What does the => operator do?

Tags: ruby, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Ruby what does “=>” mean and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663074/in-ruby-what-does-mean-and-how-does-it-work)

Just wondering what the `=>` operator does in Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It points to a value of a key in a hash :

```
{:key => 'value'}
```

Comment: It's also used in the rescue statement to assigne the rescued exception to a variable. `begin ; rescue => e ; end`