# What is the "equals greater than" operator => in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Ruby on Rails tutorial, I am asked to type:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name,  :presence => true  
    validates :title, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 5 }
end
```

I understand what this does, but I would like to know what the => operator is. In PHP-land, it links a key and a value in an associative array. Is it the same thing here? Is it a Ruby operator or a Rails operator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Ruby what does "=>" mean and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663074/in-ruby-what-does-mean-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is mainly a ruby operator that sets the value of a key inside a hash. Thus :

```
{ :minimum => 5 }
```

Is a ruby hash that has the symbol :minimum as a key that maps to the value of 5. A hash with one entry, in this example. Same for :

```
:presence => true
```

Still a hash. However, in ruby, when you have a method, you can omit the {} that surround a hash. That is what happens with the validates method. It's a method and thus the passed hash does not explicitly need {}.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks. So it sounds like {:presence => true} would also be valid, but is just not the custom in RoR, when passing a hash as a parameter to a method.

Comment: Yes, you can use it with {} as well, though people tend to omit it :) (i omit it as well)