# A lambda expression in a rails validation statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, time

I am using the [timeliness gem](https://github.com/adzap/timeliness) to do time and date validation.

My event model has a time field storing a string like "11:15", a `start_date` and `end_date` storing a Date object.

I want the following validation behaviour:

If a user tries to create an event on the current day of the year (so `start_date == Date.today`), and the time is in the past (so if it was 15:30 when the event was created and the user entered 11:30), then the validation should fail. I.e we only want events created where the **date is today** or is in the future, and the **time**, if the date is today, **is in the future**.

I am trying the following validation for this:

```
validates :time, :presence => true,
    :timeliness => { :type => :time, :on_or_after => lambda { if(:start_date == Date.today && :day_of_week.downcase == Date.today.strftime("%A").downcase) then return Time.new(:time.to_s).in_time_zone(:timezone)>Time.now.in_time_zone(:timezone) else return true end } }
```

However it is not behaving correctly. I.e I am able to create an event with the start_date of 03/08/2015 and a time of 09:00 despite it being 15:31 on 03/08/2015! Please help!

Comment: To my mind you have a big lambda expression and it's better to define a method instead of lambda. It's hard to read for me. This will become 
`validates :time, :presence => true, :timeliness => correct_time`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda doesn't make a lot of sense, because you're using symbols everywhere - `:start_date == Date.today` will always be `false`. The value of lambdas in validations is that they're passed your `Event` instance, so you can reference `event.start_date`. I agree with [@arthur.karganyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2873497/arthur-karganyan) in the comments that if you need something this complicated, it'll be easier to work with as a method.

But, you're also making this much more complicated than you need to. It looks like you have `start_date` and `time` as separate attributes, which is difficult to work with because they'll tend to rely on each other. I'd recommend making those a single `start_time` attribute instead, and then you can use [`validates_timeliness`](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) like so:

```
validates_datetime :start_time, on_or_after: -> { Time.now }
```

If you must have separate attributes, your validations might look like:

```
validates_date :start_date, on_or_after: -> { Date.today }
validates_time :time, on_or_after: lambda { |event| Time.now if event.start_date.today? }
```

This validates that the date is today or in the future, and if it's today, also checks the time. `validates_timeliness` appears to accept any `time` when `on_or_after` lambda evaluates to `nil`.

Comment: I have tried :

validates :time, :presence => true,
    :timeliness => { :type => :time, :on_or_after =>  { Time.now if start_date.today? } } however this resulted in a syntax - so i added lambda before the block, which fixed the error but the validation still fails to catch times less than the current time

Comment: Pay attention to your syntax. Your `:on_or_after => { Time.now... }` is trying to set a block as a hash value. Note the difference between `=>` ([hash rocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393872/what-is-the-equals-greater-than-operator-in-ruby)) and `->` ([lambda literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476627/what-do-you-call-rubys-operator))

Comment: Even doing exactly as you have it fails to trigger a validation error?

Comment: As in if I try : validates_time :time, on_or_after: -> { Time.now if start_date.today? } and I do a time of "11:30" and a start_date of Today it does not fail validation.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy My apologies, I was referencing things on `self` when in fact the validation lambdas receive the instance as an argument. Updated the answer with code I've actually run :)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!