# Is there a difference between this: value and this => value in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

What the title says. I've been trying to google it, but it's a little difficult to phrase it so google knows what I'm looking for (especially since I don't know the terminology).

Comment: It's called a "hashrocket": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663074/in-ruby-what-does-mean-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: :this => :that is called hashrockets and are superior in every way...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this post doesn't seem to explain the difference between hashrockets and the other syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `key: value` syntax is used in a `Hash` literal, the key always becomes a `Symbol`:

```
{foo: "bar"}.keys[0].class # => Symbol
```

When the `key => value` syntax is used, the key can be any type (including a `Symbol`):

```
{:foo => "bar"}.keys[0].class # => Symbol
{1 => "bar"}.keys[0].class    # => Fixnum
```

Answer (score 1):

The "hashrocket" syntax `=>` is used to match up any key value pair in a hash. The newer (and shorter) syntax for hash key value pairs `:` can only be used for symbol keys.

```
{foo: bar}
```

is equivalent to:

```
{:foo => bar}
```

Generally speaking if all the keys in your hash are (or should be) symbols then I would recommend the new syntax as it is shorter and reads more easily

```
{a: 1, b: 2}
```

However, if any of the keys are not symbols then I would recommend using the older, more flexible syntax:

```
{"what" => 3, :frequency => 4.43, kenneth => "Bob"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this: value` is the newer syntax for hash literals from ruby 1.9.3 onwards.

`:this => value` is the older syntax; and is valid in newer versions of ruby as well.

[Whats the benefit of the newer syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412242/what-are-the-benefits-of-the-new-hash-syntax-in-ruby-1-9)